# How can I access the router id in vuex store and to append it to Axios get method

Tags: vue.js, axios, vuex

Hi I am trying to get the id from router and to append it to axios get method.
This is the code from store.js
In normal Vue component you can do something like this: id:this.$router.id
but in vuex store is not working

```
#How can I do the same thing but in Vuex
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuex from 'vuex'
import Axios from 'axios';
import router from './router'

Vue.use(Vuex)
Vue.use(Axios)
Vue.use(router)

export default new Vuex.Store({
  // data() {
  //   return {
  //     m_id:this.$route.params.m_id

  //   }
  // },
  // m_id : this.$route.params.m_id,

  state: {
    video_key: [],
  },
  mutations: {
    updateInfo (state , video_key){
      state.video_key = video_key
    }
  },
  getters:{
    m_id : this.route.params.m_id 
  },
  actions: {

    fetchData({commit,getters}){
      axios.get(`https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/${this.m_id}/videos?api_key=7bc75e1ed95b84e912176b719cdeeff9&language=en-US`)
        .then(response =>{
          commit('updateInfo',response.data.results[0].key)
        })
    }
  }
})
```

Comment: Try using `router.currentRoute.params.m_id`

Comment: where I should replace it in getters? or in axios.get?

Comment: Is working thank you but somehow it fetches my data from the previous route when I make the request from axios I get the correct id with correct data . Just when I refresh the page the actual content is replaced from the api with correct content

Comment: Glad I could help. Please mark my response as correct to let other people know the answer. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace `this.route.params.m_id` with `router.currentRoute.params.m_id`.

You can find more details about router instance properties here: [link](https://router.vuejs.org/api/#router-instance-properties)